# PHP Extensions configurated but not working

Tags: php, curl

For some reason my php extensions stopped working (they were working fine before).

curl for example:

```
curl_init();
```

returns an `undefined function` error.

In php.ini `extension=php_curl.dll` and `extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/"` are both set and correct.

`extension_loaded('curl')` returns `false`

Cant find anything useful in apache/php error log files. Tried resetting apache.

Im running Windows 8 64bit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What says `php_info` ? Everything there?

Comment: Yup, phpinfo displays normally

Comment: Have you tried to download a different version of that library?

Comment: Yes, i tried downloading different dlls

Answer (score 1):

Try uncommenting this line PHPIniDir c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12